# How to get the value of longitude/latitude if I already know one of them for a road on a map of roads contained in a shapefile using java?

Tags: shapefile, java, geotools

I've shapefiles containing a map of roads. I need to get the value of latitude on a given road if I already have the longitude in java. Similarly, the value of longitude if I already have it's latitude. I'm using org.geotools for interpreting the shapefiles in java. Please help.

Comment: What if a road runs directly north-south (first case) or east-west (second case)?

Comment: if the value of the other coordinate is more than one, I need to return null because the point lies on the road.